# Usage of getApplicationContext on the sync adapter context

Tags: java, android, samsung-mobile, android-syncadapter

My app includes a sync adapter; **it has been working fine for years**, but recently I've received a very strange crash report:

```
Samsung Galaxy S6 Edge+ (zenlte), 4096MB RAM, Android 7.0

java.lang.ClassCastException:
1. at com.myappid.android.ScormApplication.getApplication (ScormApplication.java:34)
2. at com.myappid.android.sync.SyncAdapter.onPerformSync (SyncAdapter.java:98)
3. at android.content.AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter$SyncThread.run (AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.java:272)
```

**ScormApplication.java:**

```
public class ScormApplication extends Application {
    //...
    public static ScormApplication getApplication(Context context) {
        if (context instanceof ScormApplication) {
            return (ScormApplication) context;
        }
        return (ScormApplication) context.getApplicationContext(); // this is a line 34
    }
    //...
}
```

**SyncAdapter.java:**

```
public class SyncAdapter extends AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter {
    //...
    @Override
    public void onPerformSync(Account account,
                              Bundle extras,
                              String authority,
                              ContentProviderClient provider,
                              SyncResult syncResult) {
        // sync code here...
        ScormApplication.getApplication(getContext()).sendOttoEvent(ottoEvent); // this is a line 98
    }
}
```

Thus, it means that the returned object from the method `getApplicationContext` called on SyncAdapter's context is **not an instance of my application class**. But how can it be possible?

Here is a bit more of my code:

**AndroidManifest.xml** *(no separate process is declared)* **:**

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" ...>
    <application ...>
        ...
        <service
            android:name="com.myappid.android.sync.SyncService"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.content.SyncAdapter"
                android:resource="@xml/syncadapter" />
        </service>
        ...
```

**SyncService.java:**

```
public class SyncService extends Service {

    private static SyncAdapter sSyncAdapter = null;
    private static final Object sSyncAdapterLock = new Object();

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        synchronized (sSyncAdapterLock) {
            if (sSyncAdapter == null) {
                sSyncAdapter = new SyncAdapter(getApplicationContext(), true);
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return sSyncAdapter.getSyncAdapterBinder();
    }
}
```

**@xml/syncadapter:**

```
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:contentAuthority="@string/content_authority"
          android:accountType="@string/account_type"
          android:userVisible="true"
          android:supportsUploading="true"
          android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
          android:isAlwaysSyncable="true" />
```

Comment: Are you declaring the application class in your manifest?

Comment: @NickShvelidze of course

Comment: Application is a subclass of `ContextWrapper`, so I guess `getApplicationContext` returns the wrapped context.

Comment: Just store the Application instance in a private field at `onCreate` and return it.

Comment: @NickShvelidze well, it may be a workaround, but I'm interested what was returned from `getApplicationContext` in that case.

Comment: @NickShvelidze > _getApplicationContext returns the wrapped context_ It sounds quite odd since my code works fine on many other devices. Could you point me to any documentation?

Comment: It may be the context passed to Application at `attach(Context)` http://androidxref.com/7.1.1_r6/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/app/Application.java#188

Comment: Try `context == getBaseContext()` in `getApplication`

Comment: I'm also experiencing this problem, exactly as you said. Been working for years, but now I get these random ClassCastExceptions. My suspicion points to updating the buildSdk to 26, since that's one of the most obvious changes

Comment: @DuricanRadu my app had `compileSdkVersion` = `23`, `buildToolsVersion` = `23.0.2`, and `targetSdkVersion` = `23` when I got this exception.

Comment: @NikolaiDoronin Ow okay. The fix that we're working on right now is, trying to replace getApplicationContext() with getApplication() for Activities and Services, and also if that's not possible, just make the Application be accessible from a Singleton. I know it's not pretty but as an experiment to see if we still get the crash reports